# R: Can I use scale_color_gradient to change the colour of geom_hline in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following object:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"), `log2(FC)` = c(-0.233242394191256, 
    -0.594887873356282, -0.148130516718721, -0.261486186324127), 
        `-log10(P)` = c(1.3671239676232, 0.748621785436137, 1.36200497028613, 
        0.699204404214651)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

> df
   ID   log2(FC) -log10(P)
1 ID1 -0.2332424 1.3671240
2 ID2 -0.5948879 0.7486218
3 ID3 -0.1481305 1.3620050
4 ID4 -0.2614862 0.6992044
```

I want to make a simple plot of these in ggplot, colouring each point by `-log10(P)`.  This is all fine.  However, I want to make a horizontal line with y-intercept -0.25, and colour this as colour "10" on the same scale as the points.  Is this possible?

```
    f <- ggplot(df, aes(ID, `log2(FC)`, colour = `-log10(P)`)) +
            geom_point(size = 5) +
            scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red", limits = c(0, 15)) +
            geom_hline(yintercept = -0.25, linetype = "dashed", colour = 10)
```

At the moment the line comes out black, but ideally it would be on the same colour scale as the points:

[image: f plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *map* the colour to the colour scale. This is done by passing `aes(colour = 10)` to the `mapping` argument in `geom_hline`. You also need to put the `yintercept = -0.25` in the `aes` call too, otherwise the mapping argument will be ignored.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(ID, `log2(FC)`, colour = `-log10(P)`)) +
  geom_point(size = 5) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", limits = c(0, 15)) +
  geom_hline(aes(colour = 10, yintercept = -0.25), linetype = "dashed", size = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>